# Plotting Lidar Scan data in rviz

Tags: lidar, rviz, a200, husky, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi People,

I've been recently working on ROS with my new Husky A200 Robot from Clearpath. Platform Details:
OS - Ubuntu 11.10
ROS - ros-electric-desktop-full
Sensor - Hokuyo Lidar
Issue - rviz output for laser scan

I opened rviz in its default state using

> rosrun rviz rviz -l

Later I tried to add an interface for LaserScan and in the topics field I chose
/lidar/scan
However, I dont see any output and instead I get the error message as shown below:

> topic: no message received

> Transform:sender=/lidar/hokuyo : For frame [laser]: Frame [laser] does not exist

A simple command like rxplot /lidar/scan gives me the data from my Lidar scanner which implies I am able to communicate with the sensor otherwise.

looking forward for a reply that could help me proceed with my Lidar.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30562/plotting-lidar-scan-data-in-rviz/) by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 612 on 2012-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In rviz you should change the **.Global Options** > **Fixed Frame** to the laser frame id, "/laser" by default.

I hope it works!

---

Originally posted by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) with karma: 843 on 2012-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6